# How to checksum an entire volume on an external Linux device?

Tags: linux, putty, checksum, winscp

I am testing an external device that runs a Linux application.

The device contains a webserver and hosts a webpage which allows the user to upgrade the application by heading to the device's ip address and uploading a specific install file.

I'm trying to determine what happens if the user attempts to upload a corrupt or partial install file.

Ideally we would prevent any changes being made to the system if the install file is not valid and so I thought that the most foolproof way to prove this would be to:

1. Take a snapshot of the device's filesystem before the upload
2. Attempt to upload the corrupt install file
3. Take another snapshot after the attempt
4. Compare the two snapshots to see if anything changed.

Trouble is, I have no real idea how to do it.

I tried to use WinSCP to copy all the folders from the device to my Windows laptop so that I could perform a checksum but it gives me an error message for some of the files during the download process:

```
Received error message from remote side: 'scp: xxxxx: not a regular file'
```

So I thought perhaps there is a way to run a checksum on the device itself, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Could I use PuTTY for this?

I'm not very skilled at Linux unfortunately!

Comment: It's not clear why you need to checksum the entire volume rather than just the install file. A standard technique is to md5 hash the file and compare it with the expected value.

Comment: Hmm, ok so there is a lot of behind the scenes magic that goes on in the external device when the install file is uploaded - lots of extractions etc. So I don't really care about the install file at all, I just want to see if the device makes any changes to itself given a partial install file or if it rejects it outright.

Comment: Well, then you may want to clarify your question. "Ideally we would prevent any changes being made to the system if the install file is not valid" sure sounds like it's an integrity check on the install file.

Comment: Hmm, I more meant that I wanted to check that the device's file system didn't alter in any way if an invalid install file was uploaded. I don't want to check whether the install file itself can enable a valid install. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, perhaps I should say that a valid installation already exists on the device and when a new install file is uploaded it overwrites this existing installation. So I want to check that this existing installation is not altered at all.

Comment: The same principle would apply. Generate md5 hash of the filesystem before and after the attempted install. Note that you need to be careful in how you do that as to not get false positives - e.g. need to deal with the install file itself being on the filesystem and any files that may change due to unrelated non-install activity. Here is a post describing how to md5 an entire directory tree: [How do I get the MD5 sum of a directory's contents as one sum?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/how-do-i-get-the-md5-sum-of-a-directorys-contents-as-one-sum)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that - will give it a go on Monday!